# tsconfig.json file shows error 'is not under 'rootDir''

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 `tsconfig.json` files. The root one's config as below

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "tsconfig",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "outDir": "dist/meta-qingflow-schema",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "rootDir": "src/",
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["scripts/**/*"]
}
```

and another one's code as below

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig",
  "files": ["./copy-resources.ts"]
}
```

But this file shows error as below

`'scripts/copy-resources.ts' is not under 'rootDir'`

[image]

Comment: Because you excluded all .ts files from the script folder, in the main tsconfig, I think there is a conflict between this config and the files option on the secondary tsconfig. Probably extends works like a simple 'concatenation' of config files and doesn't priorize 'files' option, since order of appearence in json files doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What should I do? In fact, there 2 tsconfig.json is different, main is used to build project. And scripts/tsconfig.json is used to execute ts-node command.